# Can $f*g = f+g$ for $f$ and $g$ compactly supported?

Tags: functional-analysis, convolution, banach-algebras

Let $f$ and $g$ be  continuous, compactly-supported functions $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$. Can it happen that $f*g  = f+g$? Here, $f*g$ denotes the convolution
$$(f*g)(s) = \int_\mathbb{R} f(t) g(s-t) \ dt.$$

**Edit:** Discount the solution $f=g=0$.

---

**My thoughts:** My feeling is that the answer is "no". We are asking for a certain identity to hold in the dense subalgebra $C_c(\mathbb{R})$ of the Banach algebra $L^1(\mathbb{R})$. If there is a pair such that this happens, then without loss of generality, $\|f\|_1 < 1$. But then, the series
$$h = f + f*f + f*f*f + \ldots$$
converges in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$. It is not hard to see that $g = -h$ has $f*g = f+g$. I think there can only be one $g$ satisfying $f+g = f*g$, so this is the one. But, my sense is that the interated convolutions in the sum are making the support spread out. Could somebody please clarify this for me?

Comment: What if $f=g=0$?

Comment: @TheNumber23: Fair point, I added a note to disqualifying the zero solutions.

Comment: Does it help to consider the Fourier transforms?

Comment: @NateEldredge: Under the Fourier transform, $\hat f \in C_0(\mathbb{R})$, and even has an entire extension. Over there its easy to solve for $\hat g$; one just needs to take $\hat g = \frac{\hat f}{\hat f - 1}$. Since, $\hat g$ will also need an entire extension, one needs to rig things so that $1$ is not in the range of the entire extension of $\hat f$ (which misses at most one point). This may well be possible to arrange, but then I wouldn't know how to write down the inverse transform of $\frac{\hat f}{\hat f-1}$.

Comment: I would try the following: Suppose $f \star g = f + g$ and denote $a = \max \operatorname{supp} f$ and $b = \max \operatorname{supp} g$. Maybe its possible to show, that $\max \operatorname{supp} (f\star g) = a+b$? This contradicts $\max \operatorname{supp} (f + g) \le \max\{a,b\}$.

Comment: @gerw: Indeed, [there's a theorem for that](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titchmarsh_convolution_theorem). In general, we have $\inf$ supp $f*g = \inf $ supp $f+ \inf$ supp $g$, and $\sup$ supp $f*g = \sup $ supp $f+ \sup$ supp $g$.  Certainly, in the case that $f$ and $g$ have compact support, the $\sup$s become $\max$s and the $\inf$s become $\min$s.

Comment: @gerw There's no contradiction, though. For example, if the supports of $f$ and $g$ are $[-1,0]$ and $[0,1]$, then we know that the convolution has support $[-1,1]$, but the sum can have that support too.

Comment: @user103254: I was thinking much the same thing. It's an especially good point when you think about what the supports of natural solutions in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ look like. For example: $$f(t) = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{ if } t < 0 \\
2e^{-t} & \text{ if } t \geq 0 \\
\end{cases}$$
$$g(t) = \begin{cases} 2e^{t} & \text{ if } t < 0 \\
0 & \text{ if } t \geq 0 \\
\end{cases}$$
do the job i.e. $f * g = f + g$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a continuous function $f$, write $M(f)=\max \operatorname{supp}f$ and $m(f)=\min \operatorname{supp}f$. Suppose $f*g=f+g$. On one hand, 
$$M(f+g)\le \max(M(f),M(g)),\quad m(f+g)\ge \min(m(f),m(g)) \tag{1}$$
On the other hand, the  [Titchmarsh convolution theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titchmarsh_convolution_theorem) says that $$M(f*g)=M(f)+M(g),\quad m(f*g)=m(f)+m(g)\tag{2}$$ 
Since $a+b=\max(a,b)+\min(a,b)$ for any reals $a,b$, it follows that 
$$\min(M(f),M(g))\le 0,\quad \max(m(f),m(g))\ge 0 \tag{3}$$ 
So, the supports have disjoint interiors. Since the support of $f+g$ is the union of supports, equality holds in both places in (1), and consequently in (3).

Without loss of generality, $M(f)=0$ and $m(g)=0$. Fix $\epsilon>0$ such that $m(f)+\epsilon<0$ and $\int_{0}^{\epsilon} |g(t)|\,dt\le 1/2$. Let $\mu = \max_{[m(f),m(f)+\epsilon]}|f|$, which is positive. Pick $x\in [m(f),m(f)+\epsilon]$ such that $|f(x)|=\mu$. We have
$$ 
\mu=|f(x)|=|(f+g)(x)| = |(f*g)(x)| = \left|\int_0^\epsilon  f(x-t)g(t)\,dt \right| \le 
\mu  \int_{0}^{\epsilon} |g(t)|\,dt \le \frac{\mu}{2}
 $$
A contradiction.

Comment: Thanks, this looks very nice. I will read it carefully later.

Comment: By the way, the condition $f * g = f+g$ on $f,g \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ says that $f,g$ are **quasi-inverses**  i.e. that $\delta - f$ and $\delta - g$ are inverses with the "Dirac delta'" $\delta$ being a formal identity element for convolution. This is really just an technicaly fiddle which let's you talk about invertibility in a non-unital algebra such as $L^1(\mathbb{R})$. What you proved is that $C_c(\mathbb{R}) \subset L^1(\mathbb{R})$ only contains the trivial quasi-invertible element, $0$.